# Pandas - Find details from Groupby in series

Tags: pandas

I am new to Pandas and doing some analysis csv file. I have successfully read csv and shown all details. I have got two column as an object type. I have done groupy for those two columns and got all result. I need to find all endPoint from event-description series in new column. Below is the sample till Groupby operation, however I am stuck to find all kind of http endpoint. Currently endPoint is showing blank, however it may contains from http url

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('/Users/temp/Downloads/sample.csv’)
data.head()
grouped_df = data.groupby([ "event_type", "event_description"])
grouped_df.first()
```

Sample:

```
a = '{"endPoint":"https://link.json","responseCode":200}'
b = '{"endPoint":"","responseCode":200}'
c = 'app'

df = pd.DataFrame({'event_description':[a,b,c]})
print (df)
                                   event_description
0  {"endPoint":"https://link.json","responseCode"...
1                 {"endPoint":"","responseCode":200}
2                                                app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom function with `try` and `except`, because some data are not valid json:

```
import json

 def get_endPoint(x):
    try:
        return json.loads(x)['endPoint']
    except Exception:
        return np.nan

df['endPoint'] = df['event_description'].apply(get_endPoint)
print (df)
                                   event_description           endPoint
0  {"endPoint":"https://link.json","responseCode"...  https://link.json
1                 {"endPoint":"","responseCode":200}                   
2                                                app                NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for helping and giving solution. I was not sure about json. Now got clear details.